# What is the correct way of defining this function?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations, solution-verification

**Question:**

> Let's have $a$ and $b$ denote two arbitrary objects where $a \neq b$.
>
> Define a bijection $f : \mathbb N \times \{a , b\} \to \mathbb N$. The inputs to this function will be elements of $\mathbb N \times \{a,b\}$, so you can define your function by writing:
>
> $f=f(n,x)$
>
> where $n \in \mathbb N $ and $x \in  \{a,b\}$
>
> Hint: In defining this function, you cannot assume $a$ or $b$ are numbers, since they are arbitrary values out of your control. See if you can find a way to define this function that doesn't treat a and b algebraically. You may find it helpful to use piecewise functions.

**My solution:**

I'm not really sure if the solution I came up with is right. I was wondering if someone can check it.
$$
f(n,x) = \begin{cases} 
      (n,a) & \text{if } x = a \\
      (n,b) & \text{if } x = b \\
   \end{cases}
$$
Before this part of the question, in the previous part, I was asked to do this:

Draw a picture showing a way to pair off the elements of $\mathbb N \times \{a,b\}$ with the elements of $\mathbb N$ so that no elements of either set are uncovered or paired with multiple elements.

My answer for this question depended on how i drew the picture.

**Rough Picture:**

$0 \to ${a,b}

$1 \to ${a,b}

$2 \to ${a,b}

$3 \to ${a,b}

....

$N \to ${a,b}

Comment: By $\Bbb N \ast \{a, b\}$, you mean the Cartesian product of $\Bbb N$ and the set $\{a,b\}$, correct? Also, the function you've provided seems to just be the identity function between $\Bbb N \times \{a,b\}$ and itself. Shouldn't you be looking for a function between $\Bbb N \times \{a,b\}$ and $\Bbb N$?

Comment: @Brian Yes, the Cartesian product.

Comment: **Hint:** Try finding a function that maps $(n, a)$ to the $n$th even number and $(n, b)$ to the $n$th odd number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having decphered that quaint computer talk
it appears the function you quest is

f(n,a) = 2n
f(n,b) = 2n + 1